Batch inference with YOLOX
I use YOLOX detection model on video.
I created a tiling script in order to improve small detections, but it makes the process slower, especially on CPU (proportionally to the number of tiles).

This issue on the Megvii repo gave me a hint but I'm not sure if it is pertinent.
Is there a way to do batch inference to improve speed or is this process only meant for GPUs?
